# Customize default settings in VSCode linux. (enable squiggles)

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I have just installed VSCode on Debian.
I opened a file with ".cpp" extension. I'v disabled squiggles because I had some disturbing error messages. Now I need to enable them back.

I have changed ~/.config/Code/User/settings.json and added such strings to settings:

```
{
    ...
    "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Enabled",
    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser",
    "C_Cpp.loggingLevel": "Information",
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders"
}
```

But it doesn't work even after restart. These lines belong to this file because otherwise my version(1.36.1) of vscode would complain.
There is another settings similar file inside workspace folder.

The other solution from internet is to reinstall the VSCode. It's ridiculous.

I also see this settings.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/customize-default-settings-cpp
But where I can find c_cpp_properties.json ? It's certainly not in ~/.config/Code .

1) Where is that file?
2) How to enable squiggles?

Answer (score 0):

1. The c_cpp_properties.json must be created in your projects .vscode folder, see 
   https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference
2. The C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine settings needs to be set to Default or just remove the line altogether, in order to get error squiggles.